"This connection is in use by Fiber" error after upgrade to rails 7.2 and ruby 3.2.2
We meet error after app upgrade to rails 7.2 and ruby 3.2.2.
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Mysql2::Error: This connection is in use by: #<Fiber:0x00007fad145210e8 (resumed)>

It is occurred in heavy loading mode.
Why it could be happened? It looks like threadsafe error, but we do not use threads, except Puma (version 5.6.5)

Can you show the stack to know on what part of your code the problem happens ? Or maybe directly the code that triggers the error ?

I faced too with this error. This is because rails 7.2 new behaviour:
ApplicationRecord.connection_pool.with_connection do
  puts ApplicationRecord.connection_pool.stat
  ApplicationRecord.lease_connection # OR ApplicationRecord.connection
  puts ApplicationRecord.connection_pool.stat
end
puts ApplicationRecord.connection_pool.stat
# =>
{:size=>16, :connections=>1, :busy=>1, :dead=>0, :idle=>0, :waiting=>0, :checkout_timeout=>5.0}
{:size=>16, :connections=>1, :busy=>1, :dead=>0, :idle=>0, :waiting=>0, :checkout_timeout=>5.0}
{:size=>16, :connections=>1, :busy=>1, :dead=>0, :idle=>0, :waiting=>0, :checkout_timeout=>5.0}

#with_connection will no longer release connection if you call #lease_connection or #connection inside block anywhere
And #release_connection will release connection inside #with_connection block:
ApplicationRecord.connection_pool.with_connection do
  puts ApplicationRecord.connection_pool.stat
  ApplicationRecord.release_connection
  puts ApplicationRecord.connection_pool.stat
end
# =>
{:size=>16, :connections=>1, :busy=>1, :dead=>0, :idle=>0, :waiting=>0, :checkout_timeout=>5.0}
{:size=>16, :connections=>1, :busy=>0, :dead=>0, :idle=>1, :waiting=>0, :checkout_timeout=>5.0}

Also, if you work with connection from block argument(.with_connection do |conn|) you will be faced with "this connection is used by FIber" Error:
ApplicationRecord.connection_pool.with_connection do |conn|
  # # Lets imagine that we have legacy logic that call #release_connection:
  ApplicationRecord.connection_pool.with_connection do
    ApplicationRecord.release_connection
  end

  # And let's simulate heavy load to db
  ApplicationRecord.connection_pool.size.times do
    Thread.new { ApplicationRecord.lease_connection.execute('SELECT SLEEP(10);') }
  end
  conn.execute('SELECT SLEEP(1);')
  puts ApplicationRecord.connection_pool.stat
end

Solutions:
Dont use #with_connection, use anywhere #lease_connection and explicitly call #release_connection
Dont use #lease_connection and #release_connection, use only #with_connection and pass it argument anywhere
Write your own func which will repeat old behaviour of #with_connection:
def with_connection
  connection_active_was = ApplicationRecord.connection_pool.active_connection?
  ApplicationRecord.connection_pool.with_connection(&block)
ensure
  ApplicationRecord.release_connection unless connection_active_was
end

I selected solution with func
